# Short story. Humans living in cramped conditions. Overpopulation. Man finds a hidden empty large room

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this world every human is only allowed a very small space to live in.

The protagonist accidentally discovers a large empty room. It may have been hexagonal. He enters the room and joyfully discovers he can spread out both arms without touching the walls.

He is incredibly happy to have all this space to himself. Then gradually over the course of the story he invites friends to move in and share it with him.

In the end

> there are several (maybe 6) people sharing the room. One of them complains that the same sized room on another floor has fewer people living in it.

The man is planning to get rid of a large piece of furniture from the room. ( Possibly a wardrobe.)

He thinks to himself that it is a shame to get rid of the furniture but the room will seem even larger without it.

I seem to remember the author may have been  Asimov. I have searched collections of his short stories but have not yet found the one I can remember.

I read it in the 80s I think in an anthology of short Science Fiction borrowed from a library.

Comment: [_"Billennium"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billennium_(short_story))? As per [Short story about future where living space is at a premium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171561)

Comment: I will check this out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It is Billenium. Thank you @fez

Comment: Closed as duplicate after acceptance-by-comment.

Comment: @fez - honestly, you should have been the one to get the answer and the checkmark; this is why one should NOT answer questions in the comments.

Comment: I know answers don't belong in comments, I had only enough time to comment after a quick search. So no stress at all getting a formal answer and acceptance in @JeffZeitlin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely to be J.G. Ballard’s “Billennium” which has appeared in several collections of his stories. I don’t recall Asimov writing this sort of story, and I do recall this being a theme that Ballard returns to often. There's a [Wikipedia summary of the story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billennium_(short_story)) which seems to match both your description and my memory of the story.

A quote about the wardrobe:

> Settling himself, he noticed that the right-hand spire of the wardrobe, all he had been able to see for the past two months, was now dismantled.
>
> It had been a beautiful piece of furniture, in a way symbolising this whole private world, and the salesman at the store told him there were few like it left. For a moment Ward felt a sudden pang of regret, as he had done as a child when his father, in a mood of exasperation, had taken something away from him and he knew he would never see it again.
>
> Then he pulled himself together. It was a beautiful wardrobe, without doubt, but when it was gone it would make the room seem even larger.

Comment: Agreed, that's the one.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added a quote about the wardrobe.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Not at all a problem. If I'd had an e-copy of the story handy here, I'd probably have added such a quote myself.

Comment: :-D I cheated. I'm the guy who posted the earlier answer for this, and I have an archive.org link in there to where it was printed in a magazine.